# Google Cloud SDK installer fails to complete component installation on Windows 7

Tags: windows, installation, google-cloud-sdk

During installation I get a message:

Unfortunately, the component installation did not complete successfully. Please check the detailed logs for the error message.

I tried installing to all users, single user, many destinations and names.

Details:

Output folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Failed to install.

What to do?

Comment: Can you report this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list, with windows version, and what instaltion method you are using. You can also try https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned to download a zip archive, which you can simply unzip and run without installation step.

Comment: i am facing the similar issue, it was working fine earlier but when I reinstalled google cloud sdk the msi installer is giving me the similar error.

Comment: @LondonUK how you fixed this issue, as I am facing the same issue. earlier it was working and when I reinstalled not working and similar error.

Answer (score 10):

for some reason it seems it doesn't like the spaces in the path. Change to other path without spaces: like C:/some/folder/with/no/spaces/cloud-sdk

Comment: I have tried taking the spaces out but I am still getting the same error

Comment: This doesn't work when the corporate proxy is the reason but thx

Answer (score 3):

The 'find' command is a standard Windows command which has been around since the days of DOS. If it doesn't exist on your system, this usually means your PATH is broken or someone has deleted 'find.exe' from C:\Windows\System32. In either case it's not an issue with the Cloud SDK installer.

If you still have 'find.exe' in C:\Windows\System32, **you can check your PATH variable and add 'C:\Windows\System32' back to it if it's not included.**

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35907845

Comment: this should be a comment instead of answer

Comment: because u r posting a link rather then explaining.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when installing it yesterday and I tried a different sets of solutions for this.

- I created a `find.exe` path in my `PATH` variable
- I also created a `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` path in my environment variable
- I tried uninstalling Python (2.7.14, I think) and re-installing it.
- I redirected the path where the SDK is going to be installed to. The default path was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\`. I just removed the space on `CloudSDK` and it installed right after.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is a space issue in Cloud SDK folder/directory path, google cloud sdk installer adds default path as

```
C:\{USER_DIR}\Google\Cloud SDK
```

So remove space between Cloud and SDK or change path to different folder without spaces, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**I was getting this error because python was not installed on my machine. I installed python & then run the gcloud installer. It worked for me.**

No need to remove white space from installation path of gcloud

Atul