# Google Cloud SDK Windows Installer Error: "System cannot find the path specified"

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, environment-variables, google-cloud-sdk

When I tried install Google Cloud SDK by its own installer I get this:

[image: gcloudsdk]
[image: gcloudsdk3]

---

"Sistem belirtilen yolu bulamiyor" means **"System cannot find the path specified"**
And this is my enviroment variables:

[image: envVar]

`C:/HERE` where my Python executable file is.
So who is going to tell me what is going on here? Also my Python version is 3.7.6

EDIT: This part is extra and a bit long but here are my log files. I hope it helps. I am tryin to make a CRM program and I need to connect it to Cloud Services. Thanks for any help!

```
2020-10-13 00:15:24,919 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'components']
2020-10-13 00:15:24,926 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'components', 'copy_bundled_python']
2020-10-13 00:15:24,927 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.components.copy-bundled-python] with arguments: []
2020-10-13 00:15:32,618 INFO     root            Display format: "value(python_location)"
2020-10-13 00:15:32,618 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ C:\Users\ALICEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfffjhsuk\python\python.exe  
2020-10-13 00:15:32,623 DEBUG    root            Metrics reporting process started...
```

```
2020-10-13 00:17:18,590 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'components']
2020-10-13 00:17:18,598 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'components', 'post_process']
2020-10-13 00:17:18,600 DEBUG    root            Running [gcloud.components.post-process] with arguments: []
2020-10-13 00:18:41,822 INFO     root            Display format: "none"
```

Last one is a bit long so i took the last bit

```
2020-10-13 00:17:17,480 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗

2020-10-13 00:17:17,480 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ╠═ Creating backup and activating new installation          ═╣

2020-10-13 00:17:17,480 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ╚
2020-10-13 00:17:17,480 DEBUG    root            Attempting to move directory [C:\Users\Ali cem üzüm\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk] to [C:\Users\Ali cem üzüm\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.staging\.install\.backup]
2020-10-13 00:17:17,498 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ══════════════════════════════
2020-10-13 00:17:17,498 DEBUG    root            Attempting to move directory [C:\Users\Ali cem üzüm\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk.staging] to [C:\Users\Ali cem üzüm\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk]
2020-10-13 00:17:17,522 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ══════════════════════════════
2020-10-13 00:17:17,522 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ ╝

2020-10-13 00:17:17,609 DEBUG    root            Updating notification cache...
2020-10-13 00:17:17,609 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 

2020-10-13 00:17:17,612 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Performing post processing steps...
2020-10-13 00:17:17,613 DEBUG    root            Executing command: ['C:\\Users\\ALICEM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfffjhsuk\\python\\python.exe', '-S', 'C:\\Users\\Ali cem üzüm\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\lib/gcloud.py', 'components', 'post-process']
2020-10-13 00:18:41,872 DEBUG    ___FILE_ONLY___ 
2020-10-13 00:18:41,873 DEBUG    ___FILE_ONLY___ 
2020-10-13 00:18:42,044 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ 
Update done!


2020-10-13 00:18:42,049 INFO     root            Display format: "none"
```

Comment: Installer logs can be seen here in this directory:

`C:\Users\USERS\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\logs\DATE`

Could you also include the log on your post as well? Maybe we could see additional information that explains the root cause of the error

Comment: are you using windows 10

Comment: @KetZoomer yes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you double check your `PATH` variable.

As [per](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart#before-you-begin):

**"If your installation is unsuccessful due to the find command not being recognized, ensure your PATH environment variable is set to include the folder containing find. Usually, this is C:\WINDOWS\system32;"**

I noticed that you added the logs :), I would like to mention that sometimes there are some issues with special characters in the admin user name(~),so just a quick test, could you please try to use another user without any special character in the name?

Another option is installing manually Python 2.7 and set an environment variable with **"CLOUDSDK_PYTHON"** with a direct path to python.exe.

For example:

```
C:\HERE\python.exe
```

Finally, I found this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725174/google-cloud-sdk-installer-fails-to-complete-component-installation-on-windows-7) post that could help you.

Comment: I created whole new user and double double checked `PATH` variable and tried again. This time it came up with this error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 17:ordinal...` Then I found this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956657/google-cloud-sdk-install-failed-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec) and I tried what he said also changed destination folder to ` C:\GoogleSDK`. STILL GETTING ASCII ERROR ON THE SAME POSITION :(

Comment: I found a lot Public Issue trackers with this issue :(  https://issuetracker.google.com/142470928 , https://issuetracker.google.com/80379231 and https://issuetracker.google.com/80344082, also a [github post](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-eclipse/issues/3515) . I think that at this point, it would be better if you contact the GCP support team since they can help you to inspect deeply the issue :D. On my side I will continue investigating.